# Getting a second GPU to speed up rendering times in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I don’t know much about hardware so, please, be gentle!

I’m thinking of getting a second GPU to cut (Blender Cycles) rendering times in half.
After some research I found out that:

1. each GPU renders an assigned tile in Blender (hence the reduced half time)
2. the new GPU has to be of the same type (Nvidia, in my case)
3. Two GPUs can generate more heat
4. ‘I need to check the power’ (not sure what that means)

I own a
‘GA-X99P-SLI LGA2011-3 ATX’ Motherboard, with a

‘Palit Geforce GTX 1070 Super JetStream 8GB GDDR5’ Graphics Card, and a

‘NH-D9DX i4 3U 92mm Intel Xeon’ CPU Cooler

**Here are my questions:**

A. Should i get the same GTX 1070 or should I go for a faster one (e.g. the 1080?)
I was thinking of buying the same GTX 1070.

B. In terms of heat, will the PC be ok or should I do something about it?

C. In terms of power, what should i do?

D. For rendering in Blender, do i have to physically connect the cards via SLI, or they don’t need to be connected?

Many thanks for any comments and help

George

Comment: do some more research: this site requires one question per post, question not too broad and based on personal opinions, and questions about hardware are off topic... (https://blender.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: A-GPUs don't have to be the same, which one you buy is entirely up to you and your budget. Mismatched GPUs might result in wasted processing cycles for the faster GPU, as it waits for the slower one to be done rendering. Also make sure that both cards have the same amount of vRAM B To cool the systems add fans on the chassis or consider liquid cooling. C For power get a Power supply that can handle the power draw for all of the system. An 850w power supply should be enough. D For blender you don't need SLI.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the helpful reply. I have an 800w power supply and I had a second opinion confirming that it would support two GPUs. Therefore, i think I’ll go for another identical 1070. Many thanks again.